# Plotting two subplots in one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two PCA plots: one for training data and testing test. Using seaborn, I'd like to combine those two and plot like subplots.

```py
sns.FacetGrid(finalDf_test, hue="L", height=6).map(plt.scatter, 'PC1_test', 'PC2_test').add_legend()
sns.FacetGrid(finalDf_train, hue="L", height=6).map(plt.scatter, 'PC1_train', 'PC2_train').add_legend()
```

Can someone help on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) is a figure-level function that creates one or more subplots, depending on its `col=` and `row=` parameters. In this case, only one subplot is created.

As `FacetGrid` works on only one dataframe, you could concatenate your dataframes, introducing a new column to diferentiate test and train. Also, the "PC1" and "PC2" columns of both dataframes should get the same name.

An easier approach is to use matplotlib to create the figure and then call `sns.scatterplot(...., ax=...)` for each of the subplots.
It would look like:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create some dummy data
l = np.random.randint(0,2,500)
p1 = np.random.rand(500)*10
p2 = p1 + np.random.randn(500) + l
finalDf_test = pd.DataFrame({'PC1_test': p1[:100], 'PC2_test': p2[:100], 'L':l[:100] })
finalDf_train = pd.DataFrame({'PC1_train': p1[100:], 'PC2_train': p2[100:], 'L':l[100:] })

sns.set()
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 6), sharex=True, sharey=True)
sns.scatterplot(data=finalDf_test, x='PC1_test', y='PC2_test', hue='L', ax=ax1)
sns.scatterplot(data=finalDf_train, x='PC1_train', y='PC2_train', hue='L', ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

[image: scatterplots on matplotlib subplots]

Concatenating the dataframes could look as follows:

```py
sns.set()
finalDf_total = pd.concat({'test': finalDf_test.rename(columns={'PC1_test': 'PC1', 'PC2_test': 'PC2' }),
                          'train':finalDf_train.rename(columns={'PC1_train': 'PC1', 'PC2_train': 'PC2' })})
finalDf_total.index.rename(['origin', None], inplace=True) # rename the first index column to "origin"
finalDf_total.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True) # convert the first index to a regular column
sns.FacetGrid(finalDf_total, hue='L', height=6, col='origin').map(plt.scatter, 'PC1', 'PC2').add_legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: facetgrid with combined dataframes]

The same combined dataframe could also be used for example in `lmplot`:

```py
sns.lmplot(data=finalDf_total, x='PC1', y='PC2', hue='L', height=6, col='origin')
```

Comment: I am getting "ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity"
Below is the codeI have executed but its throwing error.

sns.set()
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 6), sharex=True, sharey=True)
sns.scatterplot(data=finalDf_test, x='PC1_test', y='PC2_test', hue='L', ax=ax1)
sns.scatterplot(data=finalDf_train, x='PC1_train', y='PC2_train', hue='L', ax=ax2)
plt.show()

Comment: Are you running the latest seaborn (0.11.1) and pandas (1.2.3) versions? Does your old code work with these same dataframes? Does my code with my test data work on your computer? Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66916990/edit) your question and add the full error trace (as text)?